# Is it legal to rent out an experimental aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, experimental-aircraft

Is it legal to rent out an E-AB aircraft (not a light sport aircraft)?

The aircraft will not be used for hire or compensation but to rent out to a pilot who wants to fly from point A to point B.

After reading the [FAR 91.319](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=9d4622b0bbaf3a927ce9a811f2d39c55&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1319&rgn=div8) I know the answer but seems like a lot of folks in this industry are confused on this topic.

Comment: What is the question? If it is legal to rent it?

Comment: Yes, is it legal to rent EAB aircraft for personal use.

Comment: If you know the answer, please post it.  Stack Exchange welcomes question askers to answer their own questions.

Comment: So, you've been to the authoritative source and found the answer. What do you expect to get from a second opinion? Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Look, someone already is answering me WRONG, and stating No and using 21.191(I) as the answer.

Comment: Ok, so as Steve V has already said, if you know the answer, post it. I really don't see what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 4):

Since you specifically state the question as it relates to E-AB, the reference to 91.319(f) doesn't apply. But 91.319(a) does apply.

From 91.319, the answer is "no".

> §91.319   Aircraft having experimental certificates: Operating
>   limitations.
>
> (a) No person may operate an aircraft that has an experimental
>   certificate—
>
> (1) For other than the purpose for which the certificate was issued;
>   or
>
> (2) Carrying persons or property for compensation or hire.

Your statement that "The aircraft will not be used for hire or compensation but to rent out to a pilot who wants to fly from point A to point B." is where you have erred. The FAA has interpreted that rental (or lease) of an aircraft with or without crew is a commercial operation that is "Carrying persons or property for compensation or hire."

So in the view of the FAA, renting the aircraft is a violation of §91.319 (a)(2).

You should also be aware that you could be violating access rules for your airport by operating a business that doesn't comply with the airport's minimum standards for business. That could get you kicked off the airport.

You also need to consider the conditions of any insurance policy that covers the aircraft.

That said, there's nothing that prohibits you (except possibly insurance) from loaning the aircraft to someone as long as you don't receive any compensation. Just be aware that the FAA interprets the term "Compensation" very broadly; e.g. excess fuel on return of the a/c could be considered compensation.

Final caveat: I'm not an aviation lawyer, so nothing I say should be considered legal advice. Contact the FAA, EAA (since this about E-AB) or an aviation lawyer if you want a more definitive answer.

Comment: The only NO I see is under “light sport”

Comment: 21.191 (I) is light sport I originally asked for anything other than light sport. I specially stated EAB other than light sport, like 21.191(H).

Comment: Sounds like a whole bunch of experimental survey aircraft cannot be operated for hire.

Comment: Where can I find the FAA interpretation stating renting is operation for hire?  I have seen [interpretations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2015/Greenwood-Fly_By_Knight_2015_Legal_Interpretation.pdf) that would indicate the opposite.

Comment: What is "*the purpose for which the certificate is issued*"?  I e. Does the certificate specify only for personal use of the owner? (or similar)

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be any prohibition against it. 91.319(f) applies to E-LSA but not to E-AB aircraft. 91.319(a)(2) says that no person may operate an experimental aircraft "carrying persons or property for compensation or hire," but numerous FAA interpretations such as [the Greenwood interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2015/Greenwood-Fly_By_Knight_2015_Legal_Interpretation.pdf), specifically scenario 6, makes it clear that renting an aircraft is not "carrying persons or property for compensation or hire" as long as you only provide the aircraft and not the flight crew.

The interpretation refers to the 100 hour maintenance not being required, but that rule, 91.409(b), uses the same no carrying people for hire langauge. Renting an aircraft and flying it is *not* carry passengers or property for compensation or hire, or else renting as a private pilot would be illegal per 61.113!

AOPA has a [document on this general topic](https://www.aopa.org/%7E/media/Files/AOPA/Home/Flying%20Clubs/Website%20Documents/Operating%20Experimental%20and%20SLSA%20Aircraft%20in%20Flying%20ClubsV50), which also agrees that E-AB can be made available for leasing under current law. Obviously AOPA documents are not regulatory, but it's at least confirmation that you aren't crazy for reading the regulations the way they're plainly written!

Practically, it's likely you will have problems with insurance for such an operation.